# Unsubscribe .NET event from subscriber

Tags: c#, .net, events, reference, delegates

I was asked a very interesting question about events. I think the answer is no but I'm curious if there is a way that I don't know of.

in the next code sample, can I delete the subscription from the referring class B or its Method X??

```
Class1 A = new Class1();
Class2 B = new Class2();

A.DoneIt += B.X;
```

meaning doing   `A.DoneIt -= B.X;`   without any access to Class A(nor by reflection on class A).

Comment: Your question is equivalent to asking if you can remove an item from a list without a reference to the list.

Comment: @Stilgar: It would have been possible for Microsoft to define the event mechanism in such a way as to allow event subscribers to cancel their subscriptions (e.g. rather than using `MulticastDelegate`, have a `SubscriberList` type; have it call functions that return `bool` and remove from the list any function that returns `true`).  Note that `SubscriberList` could provide thread-safe subscribe and unsubscribe messages even though `OneDelegate += AnotherDelegate` is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can only unsubscribe if you can access the event.

Delegates point one way, i.e. to a method. The method has no pointer back to the event. So the only access to the event to unsubscribe is through the type instance it's defined on.

Further reading: [Events And Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure? For instance, being class B can't you delete references to subscriptions of your own events?

Comment: It's not class B that has the event in his question.

Comment: oh, I see. Was seeing it the other way around ;-(